# Data Base Not Selected

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, xampp

I'm using phpmyAdmin through xampp as a local host and facing an issue whenever I try to use
`USE database_name;` query to select a database for work on it shows me a message database is not selected

[image]

Comment: Not sure where that error comes from, but the `use` appears to have worked according to the response in green with the tick

Comment: try a `SHOW TABLES` see if that works

Answer (score 0):

Check first you are already created the database

Then go th query and write your code

Use database_name;

Comment: Thank you for responding but as you can see I already created the database and I want to select it for work but still facing the problem

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).